# Non-standard column width in Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

This Question is regarding how to use **twitter bootstrap for non-standard web page design's .**
 I am developing a website that contains three div columns of **300px, 320px and 360px** width. The design is done by an artist, hence i could not change the width's. My HTML code looks as follows.

```
<div class = "row">
  <!-- First Column -->
  <div class = "span4">
  <!-- content -->
  </div>
  <!-- Second Column -->
  <div class = "span4">
  <!-- content -->
  </div>
   <!-- Third Column -->
   <div class = "span4">
  <!-- content -->
   </div>
</div>
```

In twitter bootstrap the column width's closest are

span4 - 300px and

span5 -  380px

**Clearly, the required width is between the too widhts**

The question is what to do when there are non-standard column sizes. Tried to find answer on the internet, but couldn't find answers. Could someone please answer this question.

Comment: Do you need all columns to change, or just this one row ? If all, you can [customize the grid](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/customize.html#variables) values to something like [that (gridcalculator.dk)](http://gridcalculator.dk/#/940/47/0/0)

Comment: @Sherbrow:
Thanks for the link to the calculator, was searching for something like that. Will try it out.

I came across a way - it is overriding the Twitter Bootstrap span width by the code below

    <div class = "span4 col1">
       <!-- content -->
    </div>

I am going to change the span width with css as below

     .col1
     {
         width:320px;
     }

I wanted to ask you, is this a good practice or will it cause problems as Twitter Bootstrap works  like approximation in different browsers and operating systems.

Comment: It is bad practice, because the `.container` will not have the appropriate width. If this is just for one row, you can do your own 3-column grid without needing the bootstrap grid.